# Ubuntu takes long time to boot

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Kali Linux in triple-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. Before installing Kali, both Win and Ubuntu boot quickly. Now Win boots normally and so does Kali, Ubuntu instead takes up to two or three minutes to boot.

[This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwa4KznQadAtdlZ2WkZiQ1N2WVE/view?usp=sharing) shows the output of `dmesg`

[This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwa4KznQadAtd2tmMG1mS2dVeDg/view?usp=sharing) shows the graphic from `systemd-analyze`

```
       548ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F378\x2d2BD1.service
       119ms dev-nvme0n1p6.device
       107ms systemd-journald.service
       104ms systemd-localed.service
       103ms gpu-manager.service
        81ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
        68ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        62ms plymouth-start.service
        45ms ModemManager.service
        41ms accounts-daemon.service
        33ms systemd-logind.service
        30ms apparmor.service
        28ms networking.service
        28ms NetworkManager.service
        28ms alsa-restore.service
        27ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        27ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        26ms speech-dispatcher.service
        26ms apport.service
        26ms ondemand.service
        26ms pppd-dns.service
        26ms irqbalance.service
        25ms avahi-daemon.service
        25ms grub-common.service
        25ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-A4DF\x2dCCAA.service
        22ms thermald.service
        22ms bluetooth.service
        20ms lightdm.service
        20ms rsyslog.service
        14ms udisks2.service
        14ms console-setup.service
        14ms systemd-udevd.service
        11ms plymouth-read-write.service
        10ms colord.service
        10ms user@1000.service
         9ms systemd-journal-flush.service
         8ms systemd-modules-load.service
         7ms systemd-timesyncd.service
         7ms kerneloops.service
         6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         6ms polkitd.service
         6ms upower.service
         5ms rc-local.service
         5ms systemd-update-utmp.service
         4ms systemd-sysctl.service
         4ms dev-nvme0n1p5.swap
         4ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         3ms dev-mqueue.mount
         3ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         3ms boot-efi.mount
         3ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         2ms ufw.service
         2ms dns-clean.service
         2ms resolvconf.service
         2ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
         2ms wpa_supplicant.service
         2ms ifup-wait-all-auto.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
         2ms dev-hugepages.mount
         1ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         1ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
         1ms ureadahead-stop.service
         1ms media-common.mount
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         1ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
         1ms systemd-random-seed.service
       815us systemd-rfkill@rfkill1.service
```

Is there anyone that could help me to bring back my Ubuntu boot time normal?

Comment: You can run `systemd-analyze blame` to get a list of the times for each service startup.

Comment: Updated the question with systemd-analyze graphic. I think bluetooth is the cause of long time boot. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, it would be better just to copy and paste the terminal output of the command (non graphic version) although I must admit the export as an svg image option is pretty neat.

Comment: To post a large body of terminal output, first, copy and paste the text from the terminal into your question. Then, highlight or select the body of text. Finally, press CTRL + K to automatically format it as code.

Comment: Actually, can you please post the terminal output instead as the text is so tiny on the svg version that I cannot read it using my browser where it is posted. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add the output within 10 hours. Thanx for your suggests about code! Anyway you should be able to download the svg and zoom in and out the image.

Comment: Added the output of `systemd-analyze`. In this you don't find bluetooth, I rfkilled it on startup but this didn't improve boot time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue! After installing Kali, SWAP partition automatically changed its UUID. It was enough changing UUID of SWAP in `/etc/fstab` to get Ubuntu booting fast back. I found the problem analyzing the output of `journalctl` command.