# Ubuntu is booting very slowly after dual boot with Kali

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-time

When I was using only Ubuntu 15.10, the boot time was very fast, it was about 15-20 seconds.

Recently I installed **Kali-Linux** rolling edition along side Ubuntu 15.10.
Afterwards the boot time of Ubuntu has drastically **increased** (Kali boots fast enough).
It takes almost **3 to 4 minutes** -> **"Ubuntu ....."** loading.

- **My system partitions :**

[image]

- **[My BOOT-CHART](http://postimg.org/image/a5wqcuqtl/) :**

[image]
 *for higher resolution click **[here](http://postimg.org/image/a5wqcuqtl/)**

- **[Output of `dmesg` is given HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15155201/)**
- **[Output of `fstab` is given HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15155745/)**
- **[Out put of `journalctl` is given HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15155773/)**

I noticed that there is a gap of **72 Sec** between line **971** to **972** in `dmesg` file.

I don't know why ?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I had the same issue just one month ago, then I found that installing kali with the same swap partition of Ubuntu, automatically changed partition UUID. Let's take a look at [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/728436/ubuntu-takes-long-time-to-boot/731526#731526), hope it can help you!

Comment: @MKay could you solve the problem? if yes please consider writing an answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Could you post the output of `journalctl` command and of `/etc/fstab` file, please?

Comment: @MKay output posted., please see the updated question now :-)

Comment: Please post also the OP for `blkid /dev/sda4`, I'm sorry I forgot. Anyway if you search for lines containing _swap_ in `journalctl` command OP you can see errors in mounting partition. I think that you could try copying UUID of `/dev/sda4` in `/etc/fstab` of Kali and substituting it in `/etc/fstab` of Ubuntu, this should solve the issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu boot slow after installing another linux distro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/824899/ubuntu-boot-slow-after-installing-another-linux-distro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.

Select Try Ubuntu without installing.

Step 1 : Reinstall the Ubuntu GRUB boot loader.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub  
exit
```

Step 2 : Correct the UUID entries in the `fstab` file.

Open another terminal and execute :

```
sudo blkid
```

Open another terminal and execute :

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Replace the UUID entries of `sda1` | `sda2` | `sda3` | `sda4`

with those of the output given from the `blkid` command.

Close all terminals and reboot into Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response with working answer :-) , This solved my problem. I can now boot Ubuntu fast. BUT!! My Kali-lost its speed :-(  please see this [***Invalid UUID error in kali***](http://postimg.org/image/wbv2rr1vt/?_ga=1.220963096.1807161352.1456053090)

Comment: @SeverusTux : You're welcome ! ... and - the kali issue has to be fixed in kali ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Re-install grub and update entire fstab is more then necessary!
if you wand the ubuntu splash-screen in grub instead kali splash-screen, yes you can reinstall grub.

kali(debian) installer, when installed belong another distro, do not take care about there have an existing swap partition so the installer format it again;
once the swap partition has been formatted the UUID has change!

The only necessary is up to date the UUID of swap partition in the fstab and in "/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume" and regenerate the initramfs to let hibernation work again.