# After resizing swap area, ubuntu is not starting

Tags: 16.04

I had 8 gb swap. THen i increased it to 16 gb on live usb ubuntu.

It did not give any warning while i was doing. Because i used the space from end of the root, not from the beginning.

But after that, ubuntu is not starting. It stays at ubuntu logo.

I went again to live usb and tried a lot of things.  One example is that
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sdX
```

i was trying to write this.

it says

> warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding. 
>   warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their  use is discouraged.. 
>   error: will not proceed with blocklists.

i dont know what to do.

also i tried this:

https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

```
grub-install error can not open directory . boot/grub/i386-pc no such file or directory
```

also trried this

https://askubuntu.com/a/229453/542960

for this part

```
sudo chroot /mnt
Install grub:

grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/ --recheck /dev/sda
```

i get this:

grub-install error can not find efi directory

what happened to my system ? i have only ubuntu, not dual

I tried lots of things. i dont want to lose my OS. please help me

This is boot info

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kdt3NFdhgh/

after i use boot-repair, it became this

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2n5K7K8xCK/

Comment: You broke your system. Since disk space is NOT allocated sequentially, from the beginning of the partition, you MUST run `resize2fs` on the partition FIRST. Boot from a Live USB/CD, backup your data (to an external drive), and reinstall.

Comment: @waltinator i dereased size of ubuntu system from the end, not from beginning. You mean reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: It seems problem solved now. I dont know how it was done. But i takes very long time open the login screen. It waits around 1 minute before login screen as black screen.

Comment: I cant again login, :( i restarted lots of times to see if no problem. again, it stucks at ubuntu logo.

Comment: I am on upstart mode. When i write ",top" it shows 8 gb as swap. I increased swap to 11 gb . When i go to live usb, i see 11 gb swap file. Why is that?

Comment: Now again did something and restarted. Black screen after i choose ubuntu on boot. And after 1-2 minutes, i can login. How can i be sure it will work forever if i restart?

Comment: Grub is not your issue, because you see the Ubuntu logo. When you see the Ubuntu logo, grub already did it's job. Likely indeed, a wrong UUID in fstab for your swap might be the issue. Boot in recovery mode and disable the line for swap in /etc/fstab. If then your system boots fine, you identified the issue.

Answer (score 0):

what @waltinator says is that you have to resize the partition correctly (see: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reduce_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html) or use tools like gparted which will do that for you. 
by the way I'm glad to hear you can boot again in to your system;
The system boot probably is slow down due the UUID of swap partition has change see this for fix it: [Ubuntu is booting very slowly after dual boot with Kali](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-is-booting-very-slowly-after-dual-boot-with-kali/1067224#1067224) It talk about get issue after installation in dual boot of kali, but that was the cause, issue was the UUID of swap change, and if you increase it you probably format and so the UUID has change.

Comment: I cant again login, :( i restarted lots of times to see if no problem. again, it stucks at ubuntu logo.

Comment: So to make faster, i should again update grub?

Comment: no it is not grub the problem but the UUID of the swap which is in the fstab, and in a couple of place, to determinate where the boot is stuck disable silent/quite option in the boot string and read the messages